# Successfactors API limit number of records return per request

Tags: python, rest, api, sap-successfactors

I'm using python to retrieve data from Successfactor API . There is a entity so heavy that the default 1000 records return per request always causes server to timeout.

I want to reduce the number of records return per request to avoid the timeout issue from server.

I have tried $top = 100 ... but can't move to the next 100 because there is no __next link in the returned result nor $offset option.

I have tried to limit the number of colums return to nonNavigationProperties. still no help.

Have anyone known how to resolve it?

below is an example:

https://xxxx.successfactors.com/odata/v2/JobRequisition?$format=JSON&&$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge datetime'2015-08-27T00:00:00' and lastModifiedDateTime le datetime'2015-08-27T23:59:59'&$select=age,appTemplateId,assessRatingScaleName,cReq1UpApprover,cReqAddSourcing,cReqAdvertCost,cReqAdvertDetails,cReqAdvertDraftCopy,cReqAlternateLocation,cReqAppID,cReqAssignmentValue,cReqAward,cReqCancelCost,cReqCancelReason,cReqCancelbyELT,cReqChangetoterms,cReqChargeRate,cReqCompany,cReqContractDuration,cReqCoreSourcing,cReqCurrentEndDate,cReqDateShortlist,cReqDescServices,cReqEstAgencyCost,cReqEstCostOfHire,cReqExtensionEndDate,cReqExtensionStartDate,cReqFirstName,cReqFlexiWork,cReqHMPositionTitle,cReqHSE,cReqHiringManagerComments,cReqHoursPerWeek,cReqInt1Req,cReqJBComments,cReqLastName,cReqLimitedTermDuration,cReqLinkedInProject,cReqMarketMapInfo,cReqMaxRate,cReqNewDate,cReqOfferTarget,cReqOriginalREQID,cReqOriginalStartDate,cReqPOApprover1,cReqPOApprover2,cReqPOApprover3,cReqPreIdenCand,cReqPreferredName,cReqPropAccumPOSpend,cReqRateCardCode,cReqRateEndRange,cReqRateStartRange,cReqRateWSuper,cReqRecSearchFirm,cReqRemEndRange,cReqRemStartRange,cReqReplacementFor,cReqRequirements,cReqResTeamComments,cReqRetainer1,cReqRetainer2,cReqRetainer3,cReqRoleInfo,cReqRosterPatDetails,cReqSecondSourcing,cReqSrcPlan,cReqStartDate,cReqStartofRoster,cReqTesting,cReqTotalPOValuetodate,cReqTravel,cReqUserID,candidateProgress,city,closedDateTime,corporatePosting,costCenterId,country,createdDateTime,currency,defaultLanguage,deleted,department,division,erpAmount,extPostEndDate,extPostStartDate,formDataId,formDueDate,instCongofStartReq,instrConfirmStarted,instrContractExtnReq,instrContractHistory,instrContractReq,instrEmpReq,instrExecAssignmentInfo,instrFurtherInstructions,instrInterview1,instrJobBrief,instrNewHireName,instrPosDetails,instrPostingDetails,instrProposedContractCosts,instrProposedExtn,instrRateCardRate,instrReqCost,instrReqDetails,instrResTimeframe,instrRoleInfo,instrSrcPlan,instrToManager,internalStatus,intranetPosting,isDraft,jobCode,jobGrade,jobGradeCode,jobReqGUId,jobReqId,jobRole,jobStartDate,lastModifiedBy,lastModifiedDateTime,lastModifiedProxyUserId,location,numberOpenings,openingsFilled,overallScaleName,positionNumber,postalcode,ratedApplicantCount,relocationCost,reverseScale,stateProvince,statusSetId,templateId,templateType,timeToFill

Comment: would be glad the get an response to my answer, at least if it helped or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using $skip?

```
https://xxxx.successfactors.com/odata/v2/JobRequisition?
$format=JSON&$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge datetime'2015-08-27T00:00:00' 
and lastModifiedDateTime le datetime'2015-08-27T23:59:59'
&$top=100&$skip=100
```

This should result in sets 100-200, instead of 0-100...

Check this: https://blogs.sap.com/2013/03/20/using-odatas-top-skip-and-count/

I think there is no "automatic" possibility to achieve this with a next-link or something else, this does not exist.
I would recommend using $count first to get the total sum. Then retrieve your page size with top and skip commands.

Comment: by the way, using SAP Cloud Integration allows you to configure the page size dynamically and splits all requests into batches... which you would manually build in python.